# Difference between subImage and subplot

Tags: image, matlab, plot, matlab-figure, axes

What it is the difference between `subImage` and `subplot`? and if it is possible, please explain me an example where I use each one.

Also, I have an example where both:

```
load trees
[X2,map2] = imread('forest.tif');
subplot(1,2,1), subimage(X,map)
subplot(1,2,2), subimage(X2,map2)`
```

Here is where I do not know what it is the difference between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `subimage`

[`subimage`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/subimage.html) (from the Image Processing Toolbox) allows you to have two images in the same figure with two different colormaps. In older versions of MATLAB, it was not possible to have two indexed images in the same figure with different colormaps (say `gray` and `jet`). `subimage` allows you to have that. This, however, is effectively no different from converting indexed images to RGB images first.

```
rgbimage = ind2rgb(indexedimage, colormap);
imshow(rgbimage);
```

And as an example:

```
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(ind2rgb(X, map));

subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(ind2rgb(X2, map2));
```

[image]

In newer versions of MATLAB you *can* specify a different colormap per axes so you could do:

```
ax1 = subplot(1,2,1);
imagesc(X)
colormap(ax1, map);

ax2 = subplot(1,2,2);
imagesc(X2);
colormap(ax2, map2);
```

## `subplot`

`subplot` is not part of any toolbox and allows you to easily organize a grid of `axes` on a figure. These axes could contain an image but they can also contain a regular line plot or any graphics object.

```
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(rand(10,1))

subplot(1,2,2)
imagesc(rand(10))
axis image
```

[image]

In your example you could just as easily use `axes` instead of `subplot`.

```
ax1 = axes('Position', [0 0 0.5 1]);
subimage(X, map);

ax2 = axes('Position', [0.5 0 0.5 1]);
subimage(X2, map2);
```

---